# How to convert a .txt file into .csv using AWK

Tags: csv, awk, export-to-csv

I have to collect data from a web page that will be turned into a .txt file. For manipulation purposes this txt has to be converted into csv using an AWK script.

The txt has the following structure:

```
    GME - Esiti dei mercati - MGP-GAS - asta (AGS) 
    Tabella esiti - MGP-GAS prezzi e volumi Esiti MGP-GAS ||

       |sessione del: 30/03/2020    |
    |
    |
    Prodotti |
    Prezzo |
    €/MWh |
    Volumi totali |
    MW |MWh |
    Acquisti SRG_TSO |
    MWh |
    Vendite SRG_TSO |
    MWh |

    MGP-2020-03-31 |8,625 |
    |4.027,000 |96.648,000 |
    |- |
    |96.648,000 |
    |

    |
    |
    |
    |
    Legenda 
    ||
    LEGENDA ||
    Prezzo  
    |Prezzo di remunerazione di cui all'Art. 103 della disciplina del Mercato del Gas naturale. 
    |
    Volumi (MW, MWh)  
    |Volumi accettati di cui all'Art. 103 della disciplina del Mercato del Gas naturale. 
    |
    Acquisti SRG_TSO  
    |Quantità accettate in acquisto da Snam Rete Gas. 
    |
    Vendite SRG_TSO  
    |Quantità accettate in vendita da Snam Rete Gas. 
    |
    |
```

The values I need to fetch and import into a csv are the ones after MGP-2020-03-31 using pipes "|" as separators. Or better:
EDIT:

```
    MGP-2020-03-31 |8,625 |
    |4.027,000 |96.648,000 |
    |- |
    |96.648,000 |
    |
```

In this format:
8,625|4.027,000|96.648,000|- |96.648,000

I have no experience with AWK, so far I've managed to write this:

```
/Non ci sono dati/{
      exit
    }

    /sessione del/{
         data =  $3
    }

    /MGP/{
        data = data $0 

        print data
    }

    /Non ci sono dati/{
        print $0
    }
```

Trying to catch the "no data" case whenever the page shows "Non ci sono dati". How can I get the values beneath the first line (the one with the 8,625 value?). Can you please help?
Thank you

Comment: What delimits the MGP data you want to get? Clearly it's not a newline, nor a pipe character.

Comment: You can't get the first value from the MGP line because you're immediately calling getline to read the line after that line that contains that first value. `getline` is rarely the right approach but if you're considering using it then make sure you understand everything discussed at http://awk.freeshell.org/AllAboutGetline. [edit] your question to show the exact output you'd expect given the sample input you provided,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how to approach your problem (and assuming a blank line or line with just `|` in the input indicates the end of the MGP section):

```
$ cat tst.awk
sub(/^[[:space:]]*MGP[^|]+[|][[:space:]]*/,"") { inMgp=1 }
inMgp {
    sub(/[[:space:]]*[|][[:space:]]*$/,"")
    if ( NF ) {
        data = data $0
    }
    else {
        gsub(/[[:space:]]*[|][[:space:]]*/,"|",data)
        print data
        inMgp = 0
    }
}

$ awk -f tst.awk file
8,625|4.027,000|96.648,000|-|96.648,000
```

Comment: It works perfectly! I won't bother you asking questions about the code's structure, but I'll try and study it since I really know nothing about AWK. Thank you!

Comment: Sounds good and you're welcome. Add `some `print` statements before and after each sub() at least to see what's happening and if you do have questions feel free to ask.